# Spray cache for get service?

Tags: mongodb, scala, caching

i am using cache headers like no-cache and no-store, i don´t know to do application level caching (maybe i could need some documentation here)
i print in console the data result when i call the method in mongodb, but it only works once after i run my app(that ocur in get service), the second time my app doesn´t print nothing, that is, it doesn't call the method.... that ocur when i try get a list of users the second time... for example, when i post something like insert new a user. i need to see the changes in the db in the frontend, my app seems get data from cache and it does´nt call the method to get the users again

the code I use in my spray scala service is

```
`package api

import spray.routing.Directives
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import spray.http.MediaTypes._
import core.UserRegister
import core.User
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import core.{User, LoginActor}
import akka.util.Timeout
import LoginActor._
import spray.http._
import scala.Some
import spray.json.JsonFormat
import spray.json.RootJsonFormat
import spray.json.JsArray
import spray.json.CollectionFormats
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONArray
import scala.util.parsing.json._
import data.UserDao
import core.UserListActor
import spray.routing.Route
import core.CoreActors
import spray.routing.HttpService
import core.Core
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorRefFactory, ActorSystem}
import akka.actor.ActorContext
import spray.routing.HttpServiceActor
import spray.http.HttpHeaders.RawHeader
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import spray.routing.authentication.BasicAuth
import spray.routing.directives.CachingDirectives._
import spray.httpx.encoding._
import spray.caching._
import spray.caching.{LruCache, Cache}
import spray.caching.Cache
import web.StaticResources
import scala.concurrent.Future


  class ListarUsuarioService(listaUsuario: ActorRef)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends Directives with DefaultJsonFormats with SprayCORSsupport with CORSSupport{


  import akka.pattern.ask
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat2(User)
  implicit val registerFormat = jsonFormat1(Register)  
  implicit val userRegisterFormat = jsonFormat5(UserRegister)  
  implicit val registeredFormat = jsonObjectFormat[Registered.type]
  implicit val notRegisteredFormat = jsonObjectFormat[NotRegistered.type]


 implicit val system = ActorSystem()
import system.dispatcher 
  lazy val simpleRouteCache = routeCache()

  lazy val simpleCache = routeCache(maxCapacity = 5000, timeToIdle = 0.001 hour)
   //lazy val cache = LruCache()

 def routeCache(maxCapacity: Int = 2000, initialCapacity: Int = 100, timeToLive: Duration = 5 seconds,
               timeToIdle: Duration = Duration.Inf): Cache[RouteResponse] =
  LruCache(maxCapacity, initialCapacity, timeToLive, timeToIdle)

// and a Cache for its result type
val cache2: Cache[Double] = LruCache()



  val listaUsuariosroute:Route =

   cache(routeCache()){
    cors{ addCORSDefaultSupport(){
      path("usuario") {   
      get {
                respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
                   _.complete {            

                     //Elemento de la lista
                     //listaUsuarios(1)              
                    UserListActor.listaUsuarios.toJson.convertTo[JsArray].prettyPrint        }          
               }    

            } 
    }
      }
    }

  }//cors

 }
`
```

I am using Cors and cache headers like no-store, public and no-cache, but it doesn´t works, even i clear my cache browser but it neither works

Comment: My understanding is that by the key, which is the route, you are saving the value, which is the full list of users. So the response is supposed to be the same until the cache is invalidated according to the rules you defined. So in order to achieve what you are describing you might need to invalidate the cache you are using for this route in another route which creates or updates users.